# C# Form - Cefsharp get Data from Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, asynchronous, cefsharp

I wrote some Code in Visual Studio 2015 C# with the NuGet Extension Cefsharp. It let you implement a Chromium Browser for Forms.

What I need is, to get some Data, from the Website the Browser is on. I want to read out a Tag and save the value in a string variable, then Parse it to a Double.

There are a few tutorial's out there - but I really dont understand the clue with the EvaluateScriptAsync() Function. I tryed everything. I dont get Errors, but neither I get the value I want in a Variable.

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#CallJSWithResult

This is the FAQ. At point 2. is the Stuff I need. For more detail, i post a example Code:

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public ChromiumWebBrowser chromeBrowser;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeChromium();
    }

    private void InitializeChromium()
    {

        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        Cef.Initialize(settings);
        chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://demo.trading212.com");
        this.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
        chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    }

    public void Dev_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chromeBrowser.ShowDevTools();
    }

    System.Threading.Thread t;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //THREADY MC SPEEDY
        t = new System.Threading.Thread(DoThisAllTheTime);
        t.Start();
    }


    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Cef.Shutdown();
    }


    public void DoThisAllTheTime()
    {
        while (true)
        {
             // HERE I WANT CODE WHICH IS ABLE
             // TO GET DATA FROM HTML (JS) AND
             // SAVE IT INTO C# VARIABLE
    }

    private void Stopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t.Suspend();
    }






}
```

}

---

At least, it's very basic code.

Can someone who have a working solution, please explain me how it works, and what I have exactly to do? Would be great, because how I said - I dont understand all the tutorials out there, and they dont worked for me.

- Cheers

Comment: Read https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#javascript-integration

Comment: Start with a button click that gets the data and work towards your target. Update your post when you actually have some code for review.